# Nested ContentControls with template

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentpresenter, wpf-style, contenttemplate

I have a custom *WindowStyle*, the XAML looks like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"
       x:Key="WindowStyle">
    /** Some setters **/
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <Grid Background="#88000000"
                          x:Name="WindowBackgroundGrid">
                        <Border x:Name="WindowContentBorder"
                                Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackground}"MaxHeight="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}}"
                                MaxWidth="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}"
                                Margin="20">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <!-- Header -->
                                <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrushColor}"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource PaneHeader_Background}"
                                        Grid.Row="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Title"Foreground="{DynamicResource DefaultForeground}"
                                               FontSize="16"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               Margin="5,5,2,5" />
                                </Border>

                                <!-- Content -->
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                                              Margin="5">
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I want the inner `Grid` in a seperate `Style` so that I can use it elsewhere.

```
 <Style x:Key="WindowContentStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- Header -->
                        /** Border control **/
                    <!-- Content -->
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
                                  Margin="5">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I use a `ContenPresenter` in my *WindowStyle*  to present it:

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowContentStyle}" />
    </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```

**Problem**

The edit above didn't give me any errors, but it doesn't present my *WindowContentStyle*. 
When I set the `Content` property of the `Window` control and load the style

```
this.window.Content = view;
this.window.Style = (Style)Application.Current.TryFindResource("WindowStyle");
```

the content is shown in the `ContentPresenter` in the *WindowStyle*  and not in *WindowContentStyle*. Because of this, the `Template` is not used and I don't have a header with a title.

How can I make my outer `ContentPresenter` pass on the `Content` to my inner `ContentPresenter` (the one in *WindowContentStyle*)?

Thanks in advance!

Greetings
Loetn

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ContentControl` to display your content, *not* a `ContentPresenter`. From the [`ContentPresenter` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> You typically use the `ContentPresenter` *in the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContentControl`* to specify where the content is to be added.

From the [`ContentControl` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> A `ContentControl` has a limited default style. If you want to enhance the appearance of the control, you can create a new `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my outer `ContentPresenter` to `ContentControl` (or did you mean the inner `ContentPresenter`?). It does show my header, but it doesn't show any content. Any idea how I've to set the *Content binding*?

Comment: I meant that you should only use a `ContentPresenter` to present content. You shouldn't try to `Style` that content because the `Style` options are limited and they won't be passed through to the actual content anyway. You should use the `ContentControl` in all other situations and you can use the `ContentControl.Content` Property to set the content and the [`ContentControl.ContentTemplate` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to apply your `DataTemplate`.